# How can I obtain an external URL's information in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As shown in the picture below, I am looking to be able to format a pasted external URL with the website's title, and first image that shows up on the page.

In this example, if someone posted the URL to this article, I would somehow want to go out and fetch the URL's  information and obtain the title - "The Conclusion Of..." and the image shown.

I'm using `React` and `JavaScript`, where would I even start for something like this? Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to obtain the title of a url using [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) and this example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28343753/11984966)

Answer (score 0):

A browser-only, *limited* solution be render the link in a `iframe`, then try this querySelector:

```
document.getElementById("my-iframe-id").windowContent.document.body.querySelector("img")
```

But this would only work if the iframe and your site are **same origin**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) for details.

So a more practical solution would require help from a server. You build an API to receive the link, then the server basically run a [scraper](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+scraper+nodejs) to dig out the first image, and send back the link to client.